# parse error while creating folder on google-drive in qt

Tags: qt, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to create folder at root(so I have not included id field) of google drive but I get error code 400,parse error.
My code:

```
void googled::createfolder(QNetworkReply* reply){
    QUrl url("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");

    QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
    //qDebug() << data;
    QString x = getValue(data,"access_token");
    QString y = "Bearer " + x;
    m_n = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    QObject::connect(m_n, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
    this, SLOT(foldercreateSlot(QNetworkReply *)));
    QByteArray arr;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QString str;
    str += QString("{");
    str += "\r\t";
    str += QString("\"title\": \"SMP\"");
    str += "\r\n";
    str += "\r\t";
    str += QString("\"mimeType\": \"application/vnd.google-apps.folder\"");
    str += "\r\n";

    str += QString("}");
    request.setUrl(url);
    qDebug() << str;
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization",y.toLatin1());
    m_n->post(request,arr);
}
```

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by the solution. Please find [your solution in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ea71ef55-f623-4bf7-880a-3b22b6450f55/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include any boundaries and file content to the request body. A proper body looks like the following.

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: your_auth_token
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_entire_request_body

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "title": "My File"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg

blob data

--foo_bar_baz--
```

It's already explain on [Drive SDK's great documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads). Please don't ask question before reading the available docs.

Comment: but my question is not regarding uploading a file but regarding creating a folder on google drive and there's no mention of any boundary question in docs for creating a folder on google-drive